# Sending keystrokes using plink

Tags: ssh, cisco, putty, plink

I'd like to execute a set of commands on a cisco device:

```
conf terminal
ip scp server enable
```

When performed manually using putty, this works fine. I'm trying to do the same using plink, but have been unsuccessful.

Attempt 1

```
plink -ssh user@192.168.1.1 "conf terminal; ip scp server enable"
```

Attempt 2

```
plink -ssh user@192.168.1.1 -m script.sh
```

It appears that an "Enter" keystroke must be sent after the `configure terminal` command. [Others](http://www.cxliv.org/2008/01/16/automated-putty-session-to-a-cisco-router-via-vbscript/). have used VBScript to send the keystroke. Is it possible to do this natively in plink instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using ' < ' insted of -m parameter.

The final command will look like this

```
plink -ssh user@192.168.1.1 -pw password_something < do-stuff.txt  > output.txt
```

In this case, your do-stuff.txt can contain multiple lines and Newslines (Enter).

Answer (score 1):

to avoid the "Enter" keystroke, you can add the -batch option :

plink -ssh user@192.168.1.1 -batch "conf terminal; ip scp server enable"